# Unable to Run JavaScript in Atom with Script package

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am trying to run JavaScript code in Atom with Script package. It can run Python successfully, but with JS files it gives the following error message:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while analyzing some JavaScript code of an extension for Chrome.

Using: `Windows 7 64Bit`  Atom:`1.24.0 x64`

Since I my coding Folder is somewhere else  I copied the files in that folder. Let’s say:

`C:\Users\USER\CodingStuff\`

then it started working.  I have also tried adding the extension file the Sources via:

1 - `CTRL+SHIFT+I`

2- `Right click -> add folder to workspace`

But that did **not** work.

Side note: `node.js` has to be installed on the system.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but if any other faces the same issue, my answer will be helpful.

Assumed that you want to run your javascript outside browser and you installed node.js.

There is a bug in "script" package of Atom. Check ur path of the script if there are spaces then this leads to the aforementioned error. Work around is remove spaces.

```
for ex:
E:\Java script\trial.js
change to:
E:\Javascript\trial.js
```